# Writing simultaneous messages to same Netty Channel with different InboundHandler issue

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, netty

We are having a multi thread application and want to avoid linear channel size based on simultaneous requests E.g., 30 parallel requests served by 30 open channels. So, we planned to use same channel for writing multiple messages with adding different inbound channel handlers to pipeline. However, certain cases the response message for one handler is read by other handler and there is a request/response mismatch. Is there a better way of handling high transactions/second (TPS) without actually creating that many channels as it does not look practical (our TPS can go upto 100, so creating 100 channels might be expensive?!!).

Please suggest how we can handle request/response matching?

Answer (score 0):

in our company, each request will add a global long value as it's unique id.
and the response return the same unique id , so you can know the response for one request.
you can generate the unique id by AtomicLong class.

Comment: Sure, we have thought about that solution. However, in that case we would be mandating the system providing the response to send back the matching id. So, we were thinking is there an other better option to avoid that approach. If nothing works out, we probably have to follow the same. Thanks for your input!